# Convert Yaml file to java objects

Tags: java, yaml

I have the Yaml File like below

```
Network:
   Input 1:
      - profile : "1"
      - size: 2
   Input 2:
      - profile : "1"
      - size: 3
   Input 1:
      - profile :"2"
      - size:100
   Input 2:
      - name :"N"
      - source: "test"
```

and am using the below dependency to convert it to class objects

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;


ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
Tiles tiles = mapper.readValue(new File(args[0]), Tiles.class);
```

My Tiles class is like below

```
    public class Tiles {
    
      @JsonProperty
      private Network network;
      public Network getNetwork() {
        return network;
      }
      public void setNetwork(Network network) {
        this.network = network;
      }
      }
public class Network {

  public Network() {
    super();
  }

  @JsonProperty
  private List<String> input;

  public List<String> getInput() {
    return input;
  }

  public void setInput(List<String> input) {
    this.input= input;
  }
```

but when parsing the YAML file using `ObjectMapper` I get an exception, e.g.     `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:`

I want to process the YAML file sequentially even though the Input is replaced by different names, I mean
I have to get Input 1 then Input 2 then so on

any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160205/parse-a-list-of-objects-from-yaml-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse a List of objects from YAML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160205/parse-a-list-of-objects-from-yaml-file)

Answer (score 1):

Use `@JsonProperty` with data from resonse i.e `@JsonProperty("Network").`

```
@JsonProperty("Network")
private List<RoadNetwork> roadnetwork;
//getter and setter
```